# Php function returns multiple array value into string

Tags: function

I want to create a function that returns string from array with comma. Before last items will have and not comma. As like I have this code...

$arr= array('arif', 'tanvir', 'sujon')

In case of one items arif or anything without comma.In case of two items, arif and tanvir or anything  . In case of three items arif, sujan and tanvir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the php implode function:

```
$arr= array('arif', 'tanvir', 'sujon')
$comma_separated = implode(",", $arr);
echo $comma_separated;
```

**EDIT:** now I understood the requirement of the asker. You need to iterate over the array and check de index of the element:

```
$arr= array('arif', 'tanvir', 'sujon');
$array_size = count($arr);
$result = $arr[0];
for ($i = 1; $i < $array_size; $i++) {
    if ($i < $array_size-1)
        $result .= ", ".$arr[$i];
     else
        $result .= " and ".$arr[$i];  
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand my question and requirement

Comment: maybe you can give a complete example of what you want. In your example you need to tell us what input you have and what is the desired output.

Comment: Thanks ddsu for your kind help & effort.